# Signing XML Document with Timestamp

Tags: java, digital-signature, xml-signature

I am in the process of setting up a service allowing to sign XML documents, for that I use the JAVA XmlSignature class.

My question is how I can add a timestamp token to this signature ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Add the timestamp to the xml data that you are signing.  SAML2 doe this with an attribute of a tag being signed with IssueInstant="2014-07-16T23:52:45Z

the timestamp is then part of the signed data and the relying application can decide on the rules it will use to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to [DSS Java library](https://github.com/esig/dss). It contains signing, as well as time-stamping solutions out of the box.
For instructions how to use it, please see the [documentation](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/doc/dss-documentation.html).

Best regards,
Aleksandr.